# I'm having some trouble while setting MongoDB to run on the cloud

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to Node.Js and all of its "accessories", and I've been trying to set up a Mongodb database, but there are so many ways to do it, it seems, that I've been quite stuck because I'm not sure what goes where and when, anyway, I have a snapshot of the code and the prompt, everything else on the code works.

[image]

Also I want to use the mongo cloud database while hosting my node.js on heroku (I got the heroku deployment running), so would I be able to test my database both when doing "node app.js" on my local machine and when I deploy it on heroku?

**Additional information**:

> I NPM'ed mongojs and mongodb
>
> I'm using some sort of cluster on mongodb.atlas (I'm clueless on this)
>
> I set up the mongodb shown on the snapshot above using the option: **Clusters > Connect > Connect your application > Short SRV connection string**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situation with MongoDB working on Heroku but not locally, getting that same error message. Here's the steps I took.

1. Make sure the database path is configured correctly - it is /data/db by default. I had to run `mkdir -p /data/db`; you can also choose to manually set that path.
2. Make sure that MongoDB is running locally **before** you start your server. You may have to run `mongod` in the command line to start it; alternately, for Node.js, you can go to package.json and edit your launch configuration by adding "pre-start: 'mongod'" to "scripts," which automatically starts MongoDB when you start your server.